# Woocommerce sort and group cart items per shipping class

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I see that there are lots of code example to split shipping costs based on shipping class, but what I want to do is to group, order and split items in cart page based on shipping classes.
So I could have:
**Shipping class 1:**
Product 3
Product 5
**Shipping class 2:**
product 1
product 2
**Shipping class 3:**
product 4

Is it possible?